# Delete From Javascript array reorder

Tags: javascript, arrays, del

I am deleting from a javascript array.  After the delete the array gets reordered.

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ];
    0 Object
       d:17065
    1 Object
       d:17156
    2 Object
       d:17246
    3 Object
       d:17065
    4 Object
       d:17156
    5 Object
       d:17338
for(d = 0; d < delete_array.length; d++)
{
    data_array[0].splice(delete_array[d],1);
}
```

After the above deletion.  The array changes to.

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object ];
0 Object
   d:17156
1 Object
   d:17065
2 Object
   d:17246
3 Object
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Use `data_array[0] = data_array[0].filter(x => !delete_array.includes(x))`

Comment: Is not really clear what is your expected ouput. Can you provide the output you would like to get?

Comment: `splice` takes an index as first argument.

Comment: please add the missing content of the variables.

Comment: There is no code in the question that could possibly re-organize the array like that.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Your code doesn't seem to match the structure you've sort of quoted. We can't help you just based on the information you've provided. Your call to `splice` is almost certainly wrong (from what you've quoted, you're passing an *object* as its first argument, which should be the index at which to make changes), but...

Comment: Oh, wait, my bad. `data_array` vs. `delete_array`. So the `splice` could be fine. Really need the details. But as Cerbrus said, there is **no** series of `splice` statements that only deletes which can turn the first quoted thing into the second quoted thing.

Comment: The delete_array contains numbers. I.e. 0,1 etc. I am on my phone now so I can't post more. The delete is working it's just reordering the array. I thought if I used splice it would not reorder. I was thinking it would just shift the remaining array objects. After deleting object 0 it reorders the entire array. I will try to get more complete code up later. But there not much more to the code.

Comment: I have figured out the issue. The array was not being reordered. It was a logic issue. I will post the solution with a link to repl. But essentially it was a logic error. When I delete position/index 0.  The next time in the loop runs then they have all been bumped up. My solution was to use get indexofarray <--- might not be correct terminology. Get the index then delete. I did use Rajesh's idea by using filter. That did work but I think it was a little slower. I will have to test further.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of messy.  But when I would delete an array object, then the order would change.  So if i delete position 0, then next loop all of the other objects have now shifted.  So i was getting the incorrect outcome.  By grabbing the indexof each loop.  I am delete exactly what I want. 
https://repl.it/K9sr/3